# promise.then not working inside async lambda handler

Tags: node.js, lambda, aws-lambda

I have implemented a simple db call here
This works and output is `success`

```
const Database = require('../utils/Database')

module.exports.logActivityLog =  (event, context, callback) => {
    try {
        context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false
        const db = new Database('config1')
        var p1 = db.findOne('logs', { id: 1 })
        var p2 = db.findOne('logs', { id: 1 })

        Promise.all([p1, p2]).then((values) => {
            console.log(db.getConnection().threadId)
            console.log('values', values)
            callback(null, 'success')
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.log(e)
            callback(null, 0)
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        callback(null, 'error')
    }
}
```

Now, if I use `async` for handler it always gives output as `null`, although my `promiss.all.then`'s `console.log` works.

```
module.exports.logActivityLog = async (event, context, callback) => {
    //exactly same as above
}
```

I need the 2nd approach to work. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
const Database = require('../utils/Database')

module.exports.logActivityLog = async (event, context, callback) => {
    try {
        context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false
        const db = new Database('config1')
        var p1 = await db.findOne('logs', { id: 1 })
        var p2 = await db.findOne('logs', { id: 1 })
        console.log(db.getConnection().threadId)
        console.log('values', p1, p2)
        callback(null, 'success')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        callback(null, 'error')
    }
}
```

Or if you want the db operations to run in parallel try this

```
var [p1, p2] = [
  await db.findOne('logs', { id: 1 }), 
  await db.findOne('logs', { id: 1 })
]
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `async/await` you should `await` your promises:

```
const Database = require('../utils/Database')

module.exports.logActivityLog = async (event, context, callback) => {
    try {
        context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false
        const db = new Database('config1')
        var p1 = db.findOne('logs', { id: 1 })
        var p2 = db.findOne('logs', { id: 1 })

        try {
            const values = await Promise.all([p1, p2])
            console.log(db.getConnection().threadId)
            console.log('values', values)
            callback(null, 'success')
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
            callback(null, 0)
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        callback(null, 'error')
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that would work. What I want to know is why then not working on lambda while it works on local node.

Comment: How are you calling your `logActivityLog` function?

Comment: Its aws lambda handler

Comment: are you using node 6 or node 8 there? async/await is introduced as of node 7.6.0

Comment: Also if an error occured you should callback with something not null as the first parameter, eg `callback('error occured')`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174337/discussion-between-mayank-kumar-and-nijm).